# Posting Form value after Authorize using return Redirect(returnUrl) in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on an asp.net MVC 4 application and I have a partial view which opens in bootstrap modal popup. This partial view has a a form tag like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Reserve", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { Id = "frmMakeReservation" }))
{

}
```

I have an action method named Reserve with Authorize attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
[POST("Reserve")]
public ActionResult Reserve(My model model)
{


}
```

when user clicks submit button on popup, Control goes to account/login and when user enters credentials, following method is called:

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
{
    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

and in If condition I get 404 error that /Reserve doesn't exist even I have Reserve view. I think after login, it needs action method with Get attribute. But I need Post action method to get values of popup in Reserve action method

Second issue is that even I used  [Authorize(Roles = "Customer")] attribute but I can get login success if a user with some other role enters login info.

Please suggest solution.

Comment: Did you check the "returnURL" parameter? and i think your router will default to {controller}/{action} right? not just /reserve

Comment: yes that points to Reserve action method /Reserve. I am using AttributeRouting so I specified ~/Reserve for /Home/Reserve

Comment: did you check that the routing is working? for your second issue, did you check that when you "login" for the second time, the authentication sessions is change?

Comment: yes routing is working fine for other controllers and actions. authentication sessions ? I see that it goes to Filters/InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

Comment: I have defined this in application_start      if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
                WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("BuyersArmorContext",
"Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Comment: did you try to use `RedirectToAction("Reserve", "Home")` instead of `Redirect(returnUrl)` ?

Comment: I'm still think in fact that 404 error, it should be because you are not type the right url, because you are using "Redirect" method, and i know why you use it, because you want to redirect to last page that your user use right?.

Comment: For your second issue, if you want to re-authenticate again, and use the authorization attribute, you need to reset your authentication sessions. if you need me to make it an answer, just tell me.

Comment: @Selman22 I used RedirectToAction("Reserve","Home") but still same 404 and the url is http://localhost:27741/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fReserve before login and after login it is http://localhost:27741/Reserve

Comment: @reptildarat how to reset authentication ?

Comment: well, just sign out like: FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); but it will get you another problem, because it's will actually sign you out, and re authenticate your user with another credentials (that they input), is that what you want?

Comment: I want that if user is not logged in then he must login before he he can accesss Reserve method.

Comment: maybe there is something wrong in your Route config, though you said   routing is working fine,but i can't see any other reason.maybe it will be better if you provide your route code

Comment: if in that case, there are will be something wrong with your authentication method. please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you need to setup login controller and redirect to the page that you want if sucessfull like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(LoginDto login)
{
    string roles = "customers, Admin"; // this is the roles that you will add into roles authentications
    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
      1,
      userId,  //user id
      DateTime.Now,
      DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20),  // expiry
      false,  //do not remember
      roles, 
      "/");
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                                       FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    return RedirectToAction("Reserve", "MyController")
}
```

and then you need to input that roles into principals when authentication happening (in Global.Asax file) :

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {
                FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = (id.Ticket);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticket.UserData))
                {
                    string userData = ticket.UserData;
                    string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                    HttpContext.Current.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then you can use the authorization attribute in your method like your code:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Customer")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Reserve(My model model)
{


}
```